# Passing data from model to gridView widget issue in Yii

Tags: gridview, yii

**This is my controller:**

```
 public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new Article('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

        if (isset($_GET['Article']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['Article'];

        $this->render('index', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

**this is my view:**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'article-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'alias',
        'title',
        'date',
        'created',
        'user.name',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "text-align: right;"),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => '',
            'template' => '{ask} {del}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'ask' => array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/mgmt/blog/update/", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options' => array()
                ),
                'del' => array(
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/mgmt/blog/delete/", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options' => array("class" => "delete", 'onclick' => 'openDialog($(this))', "data-width" => 400, 'data-height' => 200, "title" => "Delete article")
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

**and this is part of my model content:**

```
public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'createdby'),
            'slideshowImages' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SlideshowImage', 'article_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'alias' => 'Alias',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'content' => 'Content',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'createdby' => 'Createdby',
            'user.name'=> "Created By"
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('alias', $this->alias, true);
        $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
        $criteria->compare('content', $this->content, true);
        $criteria->compare('date', $this->date, true);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created, true);
        $criteria->compare('createdby', $this->createdby);
        $criteria->order = 'id desc';
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

The result of this code is a  table with data from the db. What my problem is I don't understand how the data from the search function is passed to the view ? If i do on var_dump on **$criteria**, or **$this** or in the view to **$model**, all of them is empty, neither of this is returning the data from db. Why ? Can someone explain me the cycle ? I wouldn't ask that here, but there are few documention on the Yii forums. Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$model` in the view.
`$model` have a method `search()`. `search()` only returns Data Provider. Widget use Data Provider to query data from DB.